# What exactly does invalid email address mean with Parse.com?

Tags: android, email, parse-platform

I'm using the Parse.com Android SDK (v1.10.2) and I'm trying to set the email address of the logged in ParseUser.

Any time I try my code (below), I keep getting "invalid email address"

```js
ParseUser parseUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
parseUser.setEmail(email);
parseUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
  public void done(ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
      // No exception
    } else {
      Log.d(Constants.REGISTRATION_STAGES[1], e.toString());
    }
  }
});
```

I've copied and pasted the "invalid" email address (from the output in Logcat; "timi@helloworld.ng") into the Parse data browser and it works fine.

I don't know if this is important but I'm creating users as is done in the [Anyphone (Parse + Twilio)](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/AnyPhone) example.

These are the questions I have:

1. What exactly does Parse look out for before setting email? i.e What are the properties/characteristics of a valid email address as is defined by Parse?
2. What possible reasons are there for `.setEmail()` not to work with this email address (and all the others I've tried), while pasting it into the data browser works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I made a rookie mistake, there were still quotation marks in my email string. So I was trying to pass `'"timi@hellworld.ng"'` in to `.setEmail()`.

Not all was for naught however. I can answer my two questions:

1) The email must be unique (no user must be using that email) and must not have any non printable characters.

2) Same as above.

Tip: using Apache Commons EmailValidator class helps.